# Why jQuery append() removes words after first blank space in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically generate a form after an ajax request. Below is the relevant code sample :

```
for (var i in response.responseJSON[0].fields) {
  var field = response.responseJSON[0].fields[i];
  $('#properties_form').append('<label for=' + i + '>' + i + '</label>' +
                    '<input id=' + i + ' value=' + field + '>');
}
```

My problem is that, when `var i` and `var field` are strings with blank spaces like `"Hello world"`, my label and inputs will be like `<label id="Hello" world="">` and `<input value="Hello" world="">`. However, the label text will be displayed correctly i.e. `<label>Hello world</label>`.

I've no idea what kind of sorcery that is, but I'll be very grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should consider using `attr` and `text` instead of string concat.

Comment: Because without quotes an HTML attribute can't have spaces. Your code is working fine, you just didn't write the code you wanted :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a much more robust way of doing this.

```
for (var i in response.responseJSON[0].fields) {
  var field = response.responseJSON[0].fields[i];
  $('#properties_form')
     .append($('<label>').attr('for', i).text(i))
     .append($('<input>').attr('id', i).val(field));
}
```

You won't have to worry about the content of the strings as jQuery and the DOM will handle it for you. Not to mention this is much easier to read.

Comment: Even better than previous answer indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Use `"` to enclose the attributes.

```
$('#properties_form')
      .append('<label for="' + i + '">' + i + '</label>' +
                '<input id="' + i + '" value="' + field + '">');
```

**EDIT**

This will break for the cases where the value for `i` is something like `This "works"`. Best solution is to append as jQuery or JS objects rather than using HTML string just like Daniel's answer.

Following snippet contains the correct fix for this. Updated based on the answer from Daniel.

```js
i = 'Hello "World"';
field = 'Hello "World"s';
$('#properties_form')
      .append($('<label>').attr('for', i).text(i))
      .append($('<input>').attr('id', i).val(field));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="properties_form"></div>
```

Comment: Indeed that does the trick, thanks ! Why using doublequotes solves this issue ?

Comment: @MehdiB you got to enclose attributes in strings.

Comment: It's because there's a space in the string and HTML attributes are space-separated. So the browser is seeing that as `<label for=Hello World>Hello World</label>` and renders is as `<label for="Hello" World="">Hello World</label>`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The simple solution for that has been the answer posted by Daniel now. So, I am not updating the answer like that.